# Using different variable name in hydra

Tags: fb-hydra

This is most likely not possible, but I just wanted to confirm it. 
 
I have a yaml file with verbose variable names like `stable_diffusion_server`, etc. But when I use hydra to read this data I do not want to use such a long variable name in my dataclass and would rather prefer something like this.

```
@dataclass
class AppConfig:
  sd_server: str = MISSING
```

So, is it possible to use a different name in code instead of what is used in yaml file? 
There is one hacky way that comes to mind. Basically use a pydantic validator and maybe delete that attribute and create a new one with the required name. But I don't think it would be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/structured_config.html#interpolations) to create an effective alias for that parameter.

```py
from omegaconf import II

@dataclass
class AppConfig:
  sd_server: str = MISSING
  stable_diffusion_server: str = II("sd_server")
```

But in general, this will probably just make things more confusing for you.
I suggest you decide on a single name and just stick to it in the code, config and command-line overrides.